# React hooks, select with passing value

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a select and chaging a `ref` whenever the `value` changes. So for I've got

`selectOption` got props like: `html`, `href`, `active`.

If one `option` for `e.active==true` it should be seleced from begining and anchor href should be same as selected.

```
var selectOptions = [];
  const [content, setContent] = useState(false);
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState('');

        <>
        <select>
         {selectOptions.map( (e, index) => {
           return (<OptionSelect key={index}  html={e.html}  value={e.href} />
             )})}
         </select> 
         <a href={selectedOption} class='list-of-states-link'></a>
         </>
```

Option select is a simple component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

 class OptionSelect extends Component {
  render() {
  // add some logic
  return (
   <>
    <option value={this.props.value} >{this.props.html}</option> 

    </>
   );
};
}

export default OptionSelect;
```

Comment: What is `OptionSelect`?  How does it work?  Does it take a callback such as `onChange` or `onSelect`?

Comment: so, do anyone know how to help me with it?